# java.lang.NumberFormatException when trying to fetch a line in a Cassandra table

Tags: java, cassandra, dropwizard, datastax-java-driver

I use the Datastax driver to fetch a line in a Cassandra table :

```java
 MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
 Mapper<CassandraEntity> mapper = manager.mapper(CassandraEntity.class);
 UUID id = UUID.fromString(uuid);    
 CassandraEntity cassandraEntity = mapper.get(id);
```

When the uuid exists in the table then everything works fine. But when the uuid does not exist I have this error :

```bash
ERROR [2017-01-27 14:27:24,030] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 48a3bf442525acf8
! java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "68c34e83db3o"
! at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:513) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:665) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
! at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:206) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

How can I nicely manage this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3o** is **not** a valid UUID. The sixteen octets of a UUID are represented as 32 lowercase hexadecimal (base 16) digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens). So :

- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3a is a valid UUID
- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3b is a valid UUID
- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3c is a valid UUID
- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3d is a valid UUID
- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3e is a valid UUID
- c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3f  is a valid UUID

But c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3**g** is **not** a valid UUID nor c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​‌​db3**o**

To quickly check if a UUID is valid you can use this Fiddle :        `https://jsfiddle.net/mshaffer/6e2Ljh97`

As Andy Tolbert said, when the UUID is not valid then the `UUID.fromString` method throws an IllegalArgumentException. To handle this exception, use the solution given at [How to judge a string is UUID type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041051/how-to-judge-a-string-is-uuid-type) :

```
try{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(someUUID);
    //do something
} catch (IllegalArgumentException exception){
   //handle the case where string is not valid UUID 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`68c34e83db3o` is not a valid UUID so [`UUID.fromString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) is throwing this exception, the javadocs state:

> Throws:
>
> IllegalArgumentException - If name does not conform to the string ? representation as described in toString()

[`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is an instance of [`IllegalArgumentExcepiton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html).

How are you forming `uuid` before passing it into `fromString`?  It's possible you might need to do some formatting/santization before calling `fromString`.  `68c34e83db3o` almost looks like a hex string (except for that last o).

Comment: Thank you for this answser. I use Dropwizard to invoke the fetch in database. I'm not forming the uuid before passing it into fromString. The uuid is the parameter of the method connect(@QueryParam("uuid") String uuid). The UUID c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a exists in my table. So when I hit localhost:8080/connect?uuid=c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​db3a I have no error. On the contrary the UUID c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3o does not exist in my table. Then when I hit localhost:8080/connect?uuid=c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83‌​‌​db3o I have the error I have described