# What is a valid UUID?

Tags: java, regex, java-8, uuid

I generate UUIDs, and valid them against a Regex in my code; I just ran into problems that confused me

Here is the code that generates UUIDs (in a mongodb context)

```
import java.util.UUID;
... ...

Document setOnInsert = new Document(Params.sender, UUID.randomUUID())
                                    .append(Params.userDevice, userDevice)
                                    .append(Params.hostId,"");
```

This is the code of validating an UUID; I had copied the Regex from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905929/how-to-test-valid-uuid-guid)

```
static final Pattern UUID = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})");

    public static boolean isUUID(String uuid){
        if(uuid == null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return UUID.matcher(uuid).matches();
        }
    }
```

and below are the 2 UUIDs that I have problems with

```
aa4aaa2c-c6ca-d5f5-b8b2-0b5c78ee2cb7
b24dd64c-de6b-5bf6-6283-aa2167cc93a7
```

These two UUIDs had been generated by the code mentioned above; the validating method (isUUID()) judged them as invalid in my latest debug; yet I posted these UUIDs to an online [validator](https://www.beautifyconverter.com/uuid-validator.php) , and it says ok

This is my system information

```
wjz@bj:~$ java -version 
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
wjz@bj:~$ 
wjz@bj:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
wjz@bj:~$
```

Some background: I had been working on jdk 1.8.0_111; these UUIDs had been generated then, and had no problems. then I upgraded to 1.8.0_121 today, and run into this problem...

So my question is: Whether the above mentioned UUIDs are correct or wrong? who to believe, the generator or the validation

Comment: Why not just use the UUID class to validate them? `UUID.fromString()`

Comment: Well the problem is with this part of the pattern: `[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}`. In the first one you've got a "d" where you should have 1-5; in the second one you've got 6 where you should have 8-b.

Comment: [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) has no such restrictions on the first hex digit of those groups, it just says the group consists of two `hexOctet` (which is two hex digits each). You are restricting it more than the specification does. Trust the built-in generator, distrust the "found somewhere on the internet" validator.

Comment: actually, the isUUID() is a protection before UUID.fromString() in my code; otherwise, i might got an exception if my feed of string is not an UUID

Comment: UUID of java is correct, so the prime suspect is the regex, I posted a valid regex below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foolproof way of differentiating String and UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724750/foolproof-way-of-differentiating-string-and-uuid)

Comment: [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) does restrict the first hex digit of those groups in [§4.1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.3) and [§4.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.1.1) for the Version and Variant of the UUID.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is, do not reinvent the wheel.

Basically, if you generate the ids with `UUID.randomUUID()`, there is no need to validate them. 
If you are anyway curious that **they might get manipulated manually**. 
You can just use `UUID.fromString(yourUUID)` and catch the `IllegalArgumentExcepetion` and the `NumberFormatException` that might be thrown.

Throws `IllegalArgumentExcepetion`:

> If name does not conform to the string representation as described in toString()

Furthermore, you can check behind, if the UUID got converted correctly with

```
UUID id = UUID.fromString(yourUUID);
if(id.toString().equals(yourUUID){
    //success
}
```

Comment: In Java 8 fromString will not throw an exception if the UUID is not valid. It will simply cut some digits and consider that the UUID is valid. This is a known bug, see here https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8159339 . As @JacksOnF1re mentions equals gets the job done.

Comment: One thing to look after is that `UUID.fromString` does not specify the expected UUID version, so it will guess and take whatever works. So you may also check for the version using `yourUUID.version() == 4` for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UUID.randomUUID()` which will generate a valid UUID, you dont need the regx.

Comment: thank for giving me the confidence on the generator. well, the scenario is that UUIDs were generated, yet not consumed and expired right away; instead, they might live for quite some time, might be save, copied and transmitted. so it is a precaution against any exception before using

Comment: @Jobin: we don't see where `isUUID` is called and the question already contained `UUID.randomUUID()`. The regex was just used to validate the input, so it's ok to use it.

Comment: I dont think he need to validate the UUID which is generated using `UUID.randomUUID()` (will return a valid uuid)

Answer (score 1):

Had a look at some other SO answers, other languages ..., and here is a pure Java solution which handles v4 cases (as used by default in Java 8):

```
 UUID myUuid = UUID.fromString(uuidStr); // Step 1, throws errors !
 ... myUuid.version() == 4 // Step 2, check for the version you desire
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#version--

Here is an example of a perfectly valid UUID string but version 1:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final UUID myUuid = UUID.fromString("61614667-d279-11e7-a5ac-f941ac8dfc39");
    System.out.println(myUuid.version()); // Prints 1, not 4 !
  }
```

To try out more v4 UUIDs use `UUID.randomUUID()` or online:
https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4

**Note**: `UUID.randomUUID()` of Java will work well see [How good is Java's UUID.randomUUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid)

**Security note:**

> Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID.
>   The UUID is generated using a **cryptographically** strong pseudo random
>   number generator

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects:

- Total UUID length
- Characters used
- Valid size of groups (between dashes)
- Lower case or upper case
- Valid version
- Valid variant
- Nil allowed

To have a code example, see the UUID validator implementation I recently added to Apache Commons Validator. It's not yet been merged, but you can vote for it here: https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/pull/68

Comment: Excellent validator!

Comment: Thanks, so much @fabiolimace! I also added a bean validation constraint to the Hibernate Validators. They reviewed it, but the merge takes time. Vote if you want to support it: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/1199