# How to determine if the motherboard UUID is valid?

Tags: c#, uuid, motherboard

This is an extension to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/339713/how-to-check-if-uuid-generated-is-correct), which wasn't very well-received:

As this question asked -- how do you verify the validity of a motherboard UUID? From my understanding, UUIDs are generated and supplied by the motherboard vendor. There are instances where the vendor simply just does not provide a UUID, for any reason.

The script I use is this:

```
string UUID = string.Empty;
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    UUID = mo.Properties["UUID"].Value.ToString();
    break;
}
return UUID;
```

In the event that no vendor supplies a UUID on a particular computer, the output would be:

`FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`

I noticed that in this event, the catch statement I have in place would not actually be called, since technically there's no error involved with a unsupplied UUID.

With this in mind -- how do you verify the validity of a UUID other than doing an explicit string comparison with `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`? Is the explicit string comparison even a good idea?

Comment: I see throwing an exception to that string explicitly as the only feasible option.

Comment: I'm looking at regex.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905929/how-to-test-valid-uuid-guid and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex. The first link's answer's regex doesn't work, trying it on my mobo's UUID, it returns a false. The second link's answer returns `true` even if the UUID is `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: You could convert it to a Guid type first; but why?

Comment: What is "validity" if it's more than not being a value of "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF"?

Comment: I'm not sure, Pete. I was thinking there would be other "invalid" ways other than FFFFFFFFF. But so far, Googling doesn't tell me any other way other than FFFFFF. To me, simply matching it to `FFFFF` is a bit too "rigid"; I'm not sure.. Too "dumb" I suppose..?

Comment: The issue is that eventually, validity may become an issue with making any string validity check for this.  As it is the standard for no UUID is "FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF".  If you were asking for the user to input it, I would say validity would be an issue, but manufactures have a standard that they all follow and that is the standard for no UUID.

Comment: Hi James. I see. Is there any documentation from vendors which demonstrates the "industry standard" as "FFF....FF"? I was unable to find any, other than some loose MSDN threads that talk about the FFF error.

Comment: Start here, then have fun searching through all the documentation, it may take years, but it's there.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: it also seems that all 0s is another way to identify a UUID that is null or not set as per this article. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html)

Comment: Hey James. It appears your first link to the Wikipedia UUID page, it's not about motherboard UUIDs, rather it's about software UUIDs.

Comment: And according to MSDN, you're right -- there is the potential that it returned `000...00` too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105.aspx