# extract uuid from url

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract UUID from urls.

for example:

> /posts/eb8c6d25-8784-4cdf-b016-4d8f6df64a62?mc_cid=37387dcb5f&mc_eid=787bbeceb2
>   /posts/d78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb/uid/7034
>   /posts/5ff0021c-16cd-4f66-8881-ee28197ed1cf

I have thousands of this kind of string.

My regex now is `".*\/posts\/(.*)[/?]+.*"`
which gives me the result like this:

> d78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb/uid
>   84ba0472-926d-4f50-b3c6-46376b2fe9de/uid
>   6f3c97c1-b877-40e0-9479-6bdb826b7b8f/uid
>   f5e5dc6a-f42b-47d1-8ab1-6ae533415d24
>   f5e5dc6a-f42b-47d1-8ab1-6ae533415d24
>   f7842dce-73a3-4984-bbb0-21d7ebce1749
>   fdc6c48f-b124-447d-b4fc-bb528abb8e24

As you can see, my regex can't get rid of `/uid`, but handle `?xxxx`, query parameter, fine.

What did I miss? How to make it right?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try search first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905929/how-to-test-valid-uuid-guid

Comment: good pointers. I searched wrong keywords. @fukanchik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.*` pattern is *too broad and greedy* for a UUID:

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """
... /posts/eb8c6d25-8784-4cdf-b016-4d8f6df64a62?mc_cid=37387dcb5f&mc_eid=787bbeceb2
... /posts/d78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb/uid/7034
... /posts/5ff0021c-16cd-4f66-8881-ee28197ed1cf
... """
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r"/posts/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)", data)
['eb8c6d25-8784-4cdf-b016-4d8f6df64a62', 
 'd78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb', 
 '5ff0021c-16cd-4f66-8881-ee28197ed1cf']
```

Or, you can be more strict about the UUID format, see more:

- [Searching for UUIDs in text with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136505/searching-for-uuids-in-text-with-regex)
- [How to test valid UUID/GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905929/how-to-test-valid-uuid-guid)

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions try to match as many characters as possible (informally called "maximal munch").

A plain-English description of your regex `.*\/posts\/(.*)[/?]+.*` would be something like:

> Match anything, followed by `/posts/`, followed by anything, followed by one or more `/?`, followed by anything.

When we apply that regex to this text:

`.../posts/d78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb/uid/7034`

... the maximal munch rule demands that the second "anything" match be as long as possible, therefore it ends up matching more than you wanted:

`d78fa5da-4cbb-43b5-9fae-2b5c86f883cb/uid`

... because there is still the `/7034` part remaining, which matches the remainder of the regex.

The best way to fix it is to use a regex which *only* matches characters that can actually occur in a UID (as suggested by @alecxe).