# Regex: How to find a GUID in a long string?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have this string:

```
str = 'something-rows-1973912739821738172-25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223'
```

I need to remove GUID part:

> 25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223

This is what I've so far but it isn't working:

```
c = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{12}4[0-9a-f]{3}[89ab][0-9a-f]{15}\Z', re.I)
res = c.match(str)
print(res)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `str[:-37]` if it always ends with a UUID.

Comment: `'-'.join(stri.split('-')[:3])`

Comment: str[:-37] is really neat! but the format of my input string may change in future so i need to be able to identify a GUID when there is lots of text surrounding it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653180/1517410) answer, you need this:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/6pA9Rk/1

Comment: To be clear, this answer is the one which **doesn't** match NIL UUID, `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Of course, the answer referenced also includes a regex which will match NIL and non-NIL.